# Fabric js deployment on aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, fabricjs

I am trying to deploy `fabricjs` to my `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` application. So I prepared an archive, opload it and try to deploy. On each attempt to do so I get:

```
[2017-09-05T06:11:42.483Z] INFO  [4341]  - [Application update 1.0a@24/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/50npm.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install
  bugme@ /tmp/deployment/application
  └─┬ jsdom@11.1.0
    ├─┬ parse5@3.0.2
    │ └── @types/node@6.0.88 
    └─┬ request@2.81.0
      └─┬ http-signature@1.1.1
        └─┬ sshpk@1.13.1
          └── bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.1 

  npm WARN bugme@ No description
  npm WARN bugme@ No repository field.
  npm WARN bugme@ No license field.

  > canvas@1.6.6 install /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/canvas
  > node-gyp rebuild

  gyp ERR! configure error 
  gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/canvas/build'
  gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
  gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.27-14.31.amzn1.x86_64
  gyp ERR! command "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
  gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/canvas
  gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.0
  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
  gyp ERR! not ok
```

I already tried to include `.giignore` file with

```
node_modules/
node_modules
```

It did not help.

Also I've tried to add `.npmrc` file with:

```
unsafe-perm=true
```

But still no result. Is there any other methods to troubleshoot this, because currently, I am out of ideas. Do I have to log in to the server via ssh and manually install required modules?

Comment: Almost identical error, just a different directory. I also tried the `.npmrc` file thing to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Npm install of fabricjs is trying to build and configure canvas module.
That requires dev libraries, c compiler.

canvas is defined as an optionalDeps but anyway npm freaks out if you cannot install it.

I guess it should be moved to peerDependencies maybe to help people out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I was actually wondering about that permission issue during deploy to aws. Locally I had no troubles installing fabricjs and canvas.

Comment: i have no idea where the compiling happens. Could it be that the temp files are outside your allowed writing permission? some gcc stuff i may ignore.